# How can I delete IIS objects from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, installation, wmi

I need to delete a Virtual Directory and Application pool from .NET as part of my uninstall method. I found the following code on the web somewhere:

```
    private static void DeleteTree(string metabasePath)
    {
        // metabasePath is of the form "IIS://<servername>/<path>"
        // for example "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/MyVDir" 
        // or "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool"
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting {0}:", metabasePath);

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry tree = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
            tree.DeleteTree();
            tree.CommitChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
        }
    }
```

but it seems to throw a `COMException` on `tree.CommitChanges();`. Do I need this line? Is it a correct approach?

Comment: Can you paste the full COMException?

Comment: You really should be using the windows installer to do these sorts of things.  Wix has built in functions to automatically create and remove IIS objects.

Comment: @Jesse - Using Wix can you prompt users for a new app pool/website/vdir rather than choosing existing ones (the VS Web Setup project only lets you pick existing IIS objects)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're deleting objects such as application pools, virtual directories or IIS applications, you need to do it like this:

```
string appPoolPath = "IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool";
using(DirectoryEntry appPool = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath))
{
    using(DirectoryEntry appPools = 
               new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools"))
    {
        appPools.Children.Remove(appPool);
        appPools.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

You create a `DirectoryEntry` object for the item you want to delete then create a `DirectoryEntry` for its parent. You then tell the parent to remove that object.

You can also do this as well:

```
string appPoolPath = "IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool";
using(DirectoryEntry appPool = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath))
{
    using(DirectoryEntry parent = appPool.Parent)
    {
        parent.Children.Remove(appPool);
        parent.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Depending on the task in hand I'll use either method.

Comment: is there an easy way to get the parent, when I have the child DirectoryEntry? appPool.Parent would work?

Comment: minor casing issue with "appPoolpath" vrs "appPoolPath".
other than that great answer

Comment: @simon - well spotted and fixed. ta.